# How can I have different bash setting for opening tabs and windows using ITerm

Tags: terminal

When I use terminal, I can set up something in `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` to initiate my terminal.

But if I wanna my terminal **iTerm** have different settings for opening new tabs and new windows, for example, when I open a new tab, terminal will print `Hello`, instead when I open a new window, it will print `World`.

How should I edit my `rc` file or edit the setting of my terminal emulator such as iTerm or something else?

Comment: you might have better luck getting a helpful answer, if you tell us what software you are using. There are different terminal emulators out there and tabs are not a general feature of terminal emulators. Probably the question boils down to whether or not there is a terminal emulator that allows that kind of distinction.

Comment: Oh, you are right. It probably depends on the terminal emulator. I'm using iTerm. Do you have any ideas about which terminal has this kind of function?